# A question in proof of Gilbert Varshamov Bound

Tags: coding-theory

I was self studying algebraic coding theory and I had some questions which i am posting here.

Consider this image on page 82 of the book.

[image]

> Question : I understand how " The null space of H is a linear code over Fq of length n, of distance at least d". But How is the dimension atleast k ?

Can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the rank-nullity theorem, the nullspace of $H$ has dimension $n - \text{rank}(H)$, and we know $\text{rank}(H) \le \min\{n-k, n\} = n-k$.